# Convert uploaded PNG to JPEG automatically

Tags: uploads, post-thumbnails, images

Is there a way to convert automatically uploaded PNGs to JPEGs and keep the original? In other words, let the user upload a PNG, but show in wordpress (thumbnails, large, medium, etc) the JPEG version and only show the original uploaded PNG when Wordpress request the full image.

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to do this easily, but more to the point I'm not sure WHY you would want to do this.  PNG is a better file format, and if someone uploads an image with transparency it's guaranteed to look like crap when converted to a JPG.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a way, I recommend you combine the imagefx plugin with a custom function , http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/imagefx/

You can read about it here: http://ottopress.com/tag/gd/ , and use a function like one found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201798/use-php-to-convert-png-to-jpg-with-compression

It would look something like (not tested):

```
imagefx_register_filter('custom-name','my_custom_filter');

function my_custom_filter(&$image, $outputFile, $quality) {
$image = imagecreatefrompng(&$image);
imagejpeg($image, $outputFile, $quality);
imagedestroy($image);
```

}

But remember they are not the same format and .jpg does doesn't support alpha-transparency

Comment: Yes, that is what is was looking for. I will give it a shot.